# Getting root file list in all operating systems

Tags: java, file

In java, I have used File.listRoots() method to get root file list. It works fine for windows but does not work for linux. I want it to work for all operation systems, windows, linux, mac os, etc. How can I do it?

Comment: _but does not work for linux_ Please elaborate it

Comment: It works on linux -> `File.listRoots() => [/]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There only is one file system root on *NIX systems like Linux, which is called `/`. There might be different partitions, mounted at different locations in the file system tree, but there only ever is one tree, and `/` is its root. Everything else is reachable from there.

If you want to list partitions, that would be a different question, and likely one which has no portable solution, as partitions aren't a portable concept either. For example Solaris does weird stuff in that area.

Answer (score 0):

I think this result is correct,Because java has nothing to do with your system.You may have many logical partitions in your Windows.But in linux, if you don't have to change the default configuration,then you only have a partition is "/".